# Select rows from a pandas dataframe using a set of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column named `label_id` which is a string value. I also have a set of `label_id` values in `required_labels`. I would like to select the rows of the dataframe where the `label_id` value is contained in the set.

I understand that I need to use `df.loc` for this, but when I try to generate a boolean mask that I can pass into `df.loc`, I get an error as below

```
boolean_mask = df['label_id'] in required_labels
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the series built-in func `.isin()`
The correct syntax is:

```
boolean_mask = df['label_id'].isin(required_labels)
```